# PHP Slim Rest Api

Tags: php, rest, slim

Решил написать rest api для своего приложения.
Выкидывает ошибку:

```
Type: Error
Message: Call to a member function prepare() on null
File: C:\wamp64\www\usatu\include\DbOperation.php
Line: 15
```

Как я понял prepare возвращает Null, т.е проблемы с базой данной?

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

//including the required files
require_once '../include/DbOperation.php';
require '.././libs/Slim/vendor/autoload.php';


$app = new \Slim\App([
    'settings'=>[
        'displayErrorDetails'=>true
    ]
]);

/*
 * URL: http://localhost/usatu/v1/allGroups
 */
$app->get('/allGroups', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $db = new DbOperation();
    $groups = $db->getAllStudents();
    $response_data = array();
    $response_data['error'] = false;
    $response_data['groupsStudents'] = $groups;
    $response->write(json_encode($response_data));
    return $response
        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
        ->withStatus(200);
});

$app->run(true);
```

Класс операций bd

```
class DbOperation
{
    private $con;

    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->con = $db->connect();
    }
    //Method to fetch all students from database
    public function getAllStudents(){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM class");
        $stmt->execute();
        $students = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
        return $students;
    }
```

Класс DbConnect

```
class DbConnect
{
    private $con;

    function __construct()
    {

    }

    function connect()
    {
        include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Constants.php';

        $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

            return $this->con;
        }
    }
}
```

Полный Trace

```
#0 C:\wamp64\www\usatu\v1\index.php(22): DbOperation->getAllStudents()
#1 [internal function]: Closure->{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#2 C:\wamp64\www\usatu\libs\Slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse.php(41): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#3 C:\wamp64\www\usatu\libs\Slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Route.php(356): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#4 C:\wamp64\www\usatu\libs\Slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#5 C:\wamp64\www\usatu\libs\Slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Route.php(334): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#6 C:\wamp64\www\usatu\libs\Slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(516): Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#7 C:\wamp64\www\usatu\libs\Slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#8 C:\wamp64\www\usatu\libs\Slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(407): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#9 C:\wamp64\www\usatu\libs\Slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(315): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#10 C:\wamp64\www\usatu\v1\index.php(33): Slim\App->run()
#11 {main}
```

**Update:**

```
$app->get('/allGroups', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $db = new DbConnect();
    try {
        $db = $db->connect();

        $groups = $db->query("SELECT * FROM class")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $response
            ->withStatus(200)
            ->withHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json')
            ->withJson($groups);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $response->withJson(
            array(
                "error" => array(
                    "text" => $e->getMessage(),
                    "code" => $e->getCode()
                )
            )
        );
    }
    $db = null;
});

class DbConnect
{
    private $dbhost = "localhost";
    private $dbuser = "root";
    private $dbpass = "";
    private $dbname= "schedule_usatu";

    public function connect()
    {
        $mysql_connection = "mysql:host=$this->dbhost;dbname=$this->dbname;charset=utf-8";


        $connection = new PDO($mysql_connection, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну вы даёте. У вас `return $this->con;` в `function connect()` возвращается только в случае ошибки :). Ну и в случае ошибки выводить эхом не лучшая идея. Кидайте исключение. И я бы вам советовал перейти на PDO

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо, переписал под PDO.

Comment: Ну уж если вы пользуетесь фреймворком, то не мешало бы вам разобраться с контейнером зависимостей и пользоваться DIем